# TWA Fullscreen PWA for Chrome and Samsung Internet

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, samsung-mobile, trusted-web-activity

I'm trying to turn my PWA (Progressive web Application) into an TWA (Trusted Web Acitivity) App for Android. In the beginning everything was working fine, until a user reported a problem to me.

He was unable to open the App at all, so we checked to see what could be the cause. Turns out he hasn't installed Google Chrome and is using Samsung Internet instead.

Now I did manage to get the App working with Samsung Internet so far, but with Samsung Internet the address-bar still appears.

There are a few tutorials to setup your TWA for Chrome OR Samsung Internet, but how can I combine these two? I guess we shouldn't force the user to download Chrome first. I haven't found any articles concerning this issue, so I'd be grateful if someone can link me some.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm having the same problem..

Comment: @UdoG Yes, well kind of. Check my Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After tons of wasted time trying to figure this out myself and lots of research I found this article:
https://medium.com/@firt/google-play-store-now-open-for-progressive-web-apps-ec6f3c6ff3cc

Where you can find this info:

> **TWAs work only with Chrome** today, but the API **might be also cloned by other browsers**, such as Samsung Internet, Edge or Firefox in the future.
>
> *UPDATE 2/4: The TWA works over the Android Custom Tab protocol that other browsers are currently implementing, so if the user doesn’t have Chrome or has changed the default browser, another browser might take precedence and open the TWA with the PWA content. More testing is needed to understand how it works.
>   **What happens if the user has an older version of Chrome and installs the app from the Play Store? In this case, your PWA will appear as a Chrome Custom Tab, not in a completely standalone mode.**

What that means in a nutshell: **TWA's are actually useless**, as long as you need your App to be compatible with a lot of different devices (like most do). I also noticed many Apps don't work if you disable Chrome on your Device, why I guess these are using TWA's too (and getting bad reviews on PlayStore instead).

So what I did was to dump away everything I did with TWA, and simply started using **Cordova** instead. It would have been great to have something like TWA's working just that simple, but as long as it's not working without having Chrome installed, there's no point in using it at all.

And not having this stated on https://developers.google.com directly, but fuzzy and unclear, has probably ended in the waste of time of many dev's and/or tons of Users being unable to use some Apps.

Answer (score 3):

When using a Trusted Web Activity with the recommended [android-browser-helper library](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/), the application will check for an installed browser that supports Trusted Web Activity, giving preference to the user's preferred browser.

If there's no browser that supports the protocol available, it will fall back to using a [Custom Tab](https://developers.google.com/web/android/custom-tabs) and, if Custom Tabs is not available, open the browser.

The library also contains a [WebView fallback](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/blob/master/androidbrowserhelper/src/main/java/com/google/androidbrowserhelper/trusted/WebViewFallbackActivity.java) for developers who prefer that to the Custom Tab / browser. A demo on how to use the WebView fallback is available [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/tree/master/demos/twa-webview-fallback).

Regarding the Samsung Internet browsers, it added support for Trusted Web Activity in November 2020 (version 13.0.2.9). Currently, Chrome, Samsung Internet, Firefox, Edge and others support Trusted Web Activity, covering the vast majority of users. An updated list of browser support is maintained [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/blob/master/docs/trusted-web-activity-browser-support.md).

Answer (score 1):

I just checked my TWA and it is working for particular browsers as follows:

- Chrome without any problem
- Edge on first launch shows message running in edge, later works as expected
- Opera working as expected
- Samsung browser - asks to open in browser, but works fine in browser. hides address bar if opened in browser
- Firefox(once a best browser around ...) asks to open in browser, if opened it still shows address bar